# Locking output file for shell script invoked multiple times in parallel

Tags: shell, locking, parallel-processing, xargs

I have close to a million files over which I want to run a shell script and append the result to a single file.

For example suppose I just want to run `wc` on the files.
So that it runs fast I can parallelize it with `xargs`. But I do not want the scripts to step over each other when writing the output. It is probably better to write to a few separate files rather than one and then `cat` them later.  But I still want the number of such temporary output files to be significantly smaller than the number of input files. Is there a way to get the kind of locking I want, or is it the case that is always ensured by default?

Is there any utility that will recursively `cat` two files in parallel?

I can write a script to do that, but have to deal with the temporaries and clean up. So was wondering if there is an utility which does that.

Comment: I note that `xargs` does not parallelize the execution; it runs the commands serially on batches of file names.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Take a look at the -P option

Comment: The standard POSIX `xargs` does not take `-P`; GNU `xargs` and BSD/Mac OS X `xargs` do take `-P`, perhaps to fend off `parallel`, but neither executes in parallel by default, for reasons of backwards compatibility if nothing else.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed. I did not know -P wasnt POSIX given how prevalent it is.  I only said "I can parallelize it with xargs" not that it runs in parallel by default. Not sure whether the text needs a more precise language.

Comment: No, it's fine.  Living and learning on both sides, which is what SO is for.  Well, the learning is; whether SO is living is more open to debate ;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GNU parallel](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel) claims that it:

> makes sure output from the commands is
>   the same output as you would get had
>   you run the commands sequentially

If that's the case, then I presume it should be safe to simple pipe the output to your file and let `parallel` handle the intermediate data.

Use the [`-k` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__keep_order_of_output_same_as_order_of_input) to maintain the order of the output.

#### Update: (non-Perl solution)

Another alternative would be [prll](http://prll.sourceforge.net/), which is implemented with shell functions with some C extensions. It is less feature-rich compared to `GNU parallel` but should the the job for basic use cases.

The feature listing claims:

> Does internal buffering and locking to
>   prevent mangling/interleaving of
>   output from separate jobs.

so it should meet your needs as long as order of output is not important

However, note on the following statement on [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_prll_and_gnu_parallel):

> prll generates a lot of status
>   information on STDERR which makes it
>   harder to use the STDERR output of the
>   job directly as input for another
>   program.

---

*Disclaimer: I've tried neither of the tools and am merely quoting from their respective docs.*

Comment: Ah I see, that is nice. The box I have to run it on does not have perl unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, try looking at alternatives to GNU parallel (listed here: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_gnu_parallel_and_alternatives) such as xjobs and ppss. No idea how they handle stdout though.

Comment: Had a quick scan at their docs, and prll seems like possible alternative. Updated answer. Good luck.

Comment: Funny because I converged on prll too. Thanks for following up. I intend to look at the code to see how they achieve it. They must be doing the buffering themselves, in per process pipes or tmp files